# Check if a given string is valid romaji

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

Your program is given a string consisting entirely of lowercase letters at STDIN (or closest alternative). The program must then output a truthy or falsey value, depending on whether the input is valid romaji.

### Rules:

- It must be possible to divide the entire string into a sequence of kana without any leftover characters.
- Each kana can be a single vowel (`aeiou`)
- Each kana can also be a consonant p, g, z, b, d, k, s, t, n, h, m, or r followed by a vowel. For example, ka and te are valid kana, but qa is not.
- The exceptions to the above rule are that zi, di, du, si, ti, and tu are not valid kana.
- The following are also valid kana: n, wa, wo, ya, yu, yo, ji, vu, fu, chi, shi, tsu.
- If a particular consonant is valid before an i (i.e ki, pi), the i can be replaced by a ya, yu, or yo and still be valid (i.e kya, kyu, kyo)
- Exceptions to the above rule are chi and shi, for which the y has to be dropped too (i.e cha, chu, cho, sha, shu, sho)
- It is also valid to double consonants if they are the first character of a kana (kka is valid but chhi is not)
- Shortest answer wins. All regular loopholes are disallowed.

### List of all valid kana:

```
Can have double consonant:

ba, bu, be, bo, bi
ga, gu, ge, go, gi
ha, hu, he, ho, hi
ka, ku, ke, ko, ki
ma, mu, me, mo, mi
na, nu, ne, no, ni
pa, pu, pe, po, pi
ra, ru, re, ro, ri
sa, su, se, so,
za, zu, ze, zo,
da,     de, do,
ta,     te, to,
wa,         wo,
ya, yu,     yo,
    fu,
    vu
                ji

Can not have double consonant:

a, i, u, e, o, 
    tsu,
chi, cha, cho, chu,
shi, sha, sho, shu,
n
```

### Test cases

Pass:

```
kyoto
watashi
tsunami
bunpu
yappari
```

Fail:

```
yi
chhi
zhi
kyi
```

Comment: How do we win? Is this a code golf?

Comment: Need test cases. Also could do with a list of all valid kana instead of the rules

Comment: @RobertFraser both is preferred - test cases are not rules

Comment: If `pa pi pu pe po` are valid kana, then can't you simply group `p` with the other consonants?

Comment: I added all the kana, I think. Please tell me if I missed some.

Comment: @ValueInk good point, that makes it easier to understand

Comment: "If a particular consonant is valid before an i (i.e ki, pi), the i can be replaced by a ya, yu, or yo and still be valid (i.e kya, kyu, kyo)" The list seems to be missing these for "h", and "p"

Comment: The list is missing all doubled consonant variants. Is `chchi` valid or not (i.e. is `ch` considered a character)?

Comment: I've updated list of valid kana, but `n` needs clarification

Comment: `n` cannot be doubled. I know enough about the Japanese alphabets to say that. If `n` was doubled, it would need to have a vowel after, but then it wouldn't be `n`. So if `kanna` was a word (just making it up), it'd actually be `ka n na`.

Comment: You know, I wanted to make a solution using `unicodedata`, but it'll definitely be longer than a regex solution. [Partial program](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#NY07DsMgEER7n2I7Qz6WMEmRIjfwDSwXyMZhJfPRAsrxybpI8Yqn0cy0naKHGnCNm91MMYA@RSqXbnrPwXgrzsyRQCmHnA4sQs53tQxH/FoSco8ECBiATPhYoUb91Dc1PvRLLte@5AqrQ8YwkamQ2TN7Zs@u9v/VLhGGAlNrZ42vsf8B)

Comment: @mbomb007 Does it output vowels twice intended?

Comment: @DeadPossum This isn't a solution. If I were going to use it, I'd be checking if the list *contains* something.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>96</s> 149 bytes

Regex solution to match all the valid kana. Interestingly, "ecchi" is not valid according to the current rules, but perhaps it's for the best.

```ruby
->s{s.gsub(/(?![dt]u)(sh|ch|([gbknhmrp])\2?y?|([zdst])\3?)?[auo]|(\g<2>)?\4?[ie]|(\g<3>)\5?e|ww?[ao]|n|tsu|([fv])\6?u|jj?i|j?y?[aou]|yy[aou]/){}==""}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#JY7dbuMgEEbveYpJWq2MojhVs9urJjxIHFVjmxjiGCzD1CKlz56OuxKI@TnfEU@rieoEWycuh@qxPYavUHaB6mJXqNWpjWeSRTC5Mbk4dXXvzDCNZ1m9qqR4cm9D5G6vpDoh@XMuqu799ShV9VedrP7f74@y@qd0nmeGmHE5BuLw5ZOjb4ry9apsvrKR13TOKf2@O/n1fTis19@PkWKAxvhhLG9XCrHYv8jNGjKsN88fZWjQFbtq3uxkibebKv5cZBn9R3gkKxpjrLjz7bm580nEpRZNY1AEk5AJNvPMRy9mjBgY5v85HKyoyY0kEo4jTpxF1/uewCFE7ZgD57m6axADtr7W0OOEkLDDqCH62kZkEwjD7noRTwTLxMKI0S@rVgs/eNtqmD3QhN2CuMUies/24LnkVYs2LvoOE/bEH/fktIPEhLFuRnB2ienVDw) feat. Cruel Angel's Thesis

Comment: It failes on simple tests `zi` and `zye`

Comment: @DeadPossum fixed.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 166 bytes

Long regex solution
[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#PYtNbsMgEIX3OQW7AQlFapeRfIPcgLLADqmnjgHx0wSX@uousOgsvvfpad51@Dgeah1virwuXp9DGimI8XNeVuO83KlQyWqUJTeRrIiwyb2XsohbbK6tLM@aNai4f8u9xMBSoV97EVOQM6P4P899W6eVqI2Es9fuoSZNYQcOP2/8/RcYB@AvNgwAJ1yd9ZF4fdytJ0jQEAFLttHW96eKKsxYLYZk1NpsTMalmlk5p3xrcsM097@tc@nV1pE1yMuJ1HMeTSTIyZUiO/4A)

I think that f-strings from 3.[something] python can help to shorten it by replacing repeated `[auo` and `{1,2}`.
Unfortunatetly I can't check it by myself now :c

```
import re
lambda x:re.sub('[bghkmnpr]~([auoei]|y[auo])|[sz]~[auoe]|[dt]~[aeo]|w~[ao]|([fv]~|ts)u|(j~|[cs]h)(i|y[auo])|y~[auo]|[auoien]'.replace('~','{1,2}'),'',x)==''
```

Comment: `re.sub('~','{1,2}',(your regex)` is shorter than `(your regex).replace('~','{1,2}')` by 1 byte.

Comment: Your regex is also failing on a simple test case: `bku`. Doubled consonants have to be the *same consonant*.